# Add predictor variable names to new column in model.sel table (MUMIn)

Tags: model

Trying to add the predictor variable names for each model being compared in a MuMIn::model.sel table. I realize the variables (and their slope coefficients) are presented as columns in the model.sel table, but I want to tidy up the table for presentation (dropping the slope coefficient columns) and present the combinations of predictor variables used for each model in a single column.

Using this site: https://sites.google.com/site/rforfishandwildlifegrads/home/mumin_usage_examples

I found this line:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(sel.table)) sel.table$Model[i]<- as.character(formula(paste(sel.table$Model[i])))[3]
```

Can't seem to get it to work. Hope somebody can suggest a solution.

Example:

```
library(MuMIn)

options(na.action = "na.fail")
```

## Create a data frame with predictor variables and response variable

```
data <- data.frame(
  y = rnorm(100), # Response variable
  x1 = rnorm(100), # Predictor variable 1
  x2 = rnorm(100), # Predictor variable 2
  x3 = rnorm(100) # Predictor variable 3
)
```

## Create all possible models with the predictor variables

```
model_test<- dredge(lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = data))
```

## Extract the table of model probabilities, AICc values, and model coefficients

```
model_stats <- model.sel(model_test)
model_stats

Global model call: lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = data)
---
Model selection table 
  (Intrc)       x1        x2      x3 df   logLik  AICc delta weight
1 0.09936                             2 -142.863 289.8  0.00  0.332
5 0.10750                    0.08538  3 -142.463 291.2  1.33  0.171
2 0.08760 -0.08466                    3 -142.529 291.3  1.46  0.160
3 0.09928          -0.001187          3 -142.863 292.0  2.13  0.115
6 0.09548 -0.08872           0.08883  4 -142.094 292.6  2.76  0.083
7 0.10810           0.008249 0.08621  4 -142.460 293.3  3.49  0.058
4 0.08709 -0.08511 -0.006603          4 -142.527 293.5  3.63  0.054
8 0.09573 -0.08853  0.002934 0.08912  5 -142.093 294.8  4.98  0.028
Models ranked by AICc(x)
```

## Create a column to combine and store the predictor variable names for each model being compared

```
model_stats$predictors <- .............
```